# Subsetting a Cell Data Set within Monocle

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

If anyone has any experience using the monocle package in R:

I am trying to subset my data based on a vector of sample names, but I cannot accomplish it.

I have tried:

```
x@phenoData$sampleNames <- example.cells
```

but I am getting this error:

> replacement has 661 rows, data has 5809

The object I am trying to subset is a Cell Data Set (CDS) created from a Seurat object by the importCDS function.

I have also assigned a Cell Type to every sample that is called "CellType" which is part of the meta.data of the Seurat object and is listed under the varLabels slot of the phenoData after it is converted to a CDS.

I would like help subsetting based on either of these variables, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [monocle tutorial](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle-release/docs/#filtering-low-quality-cells-recommended) low quality cells were filtered with this code (*HSSM* is the monocle object):

```
valid_cells <- row.names(subset(pData(HSMM),
            Cells.in.Well == 1 &
            Control == FALSE &
            Clump == FALSE &
            Debris == FALSE &
            Mapped.Fragments > 1000000))
HSMM <- HSMM[,valid_cells]
```

So for your example this should work:

```
x = x[,example.cells]
```

or (directly from Seurat):

```
x = x[,rownames(data.seurat@meta.data[data.seurat@meta.data$CellType == "interesting_cell",])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `x@phenoData$sampleNames <- example.cells` is adding new data to the dataframe representing your sample treatments, instead of subsetting.

Try using `x@phenoData$sampleNames %in% example.cells` to retrieve a boolean vector (True, False) and filter using this:

`x@phenoData[x@phenoData$sampleNames %in% example.cells,]`

One small edit, this may mess up your CDS data structure, so be careful. It may be better to filter prior to generating the CDS or generate a new one from the old data.

Comment: Ok, so I found out I can use x.subset <- x[,example.cells] to subset the data.  This method seems to work fine, but i am worried about what you said about messing up the CDS  data structure.  I can subset a Seurat object just fine outside of monocle, but when I try to use the importCDS function, it references the raw.data slot of the Seurat object.  This causes the function to not work because I get the same row replacement error.  Do you know if there is a way around this other than deleting the raw.data portion of the object?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Seurat. Given the complex data structure, I imagine the authors would have built a filter/subset function for removing low-quality samples which you may be able to use but you would have to check the documentation.